# Work Manager not scheduling Work with setInitialDelay

Tags: android, android-workmanager

So I have a Worker that has to run the next day from when it's scheduled. So if the work is activated at today night 8PM, then I need the work to be executed at next day 9AM. So I am using `OneTimeWorkRequest` with a `setInitialDelay()`.

Here is the code

```
val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
// calculate the timestamp for next dat 9AM 
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9) 
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
// next day
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)

val tomorrowTime = calendar.timeInMillis
val timeDiffBetweenNowAndTomorrow = tomorrowTime - currentTime

Timber.i("Tomorrow date is ${calendar.timeInMillis}")
Timber.i("Difference between now and tomorrow ${timeDiffBetweenNowAndTomorrow}")

val randomWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<RandomWallpaperWorker>()
                    .setInitialDelay(timeDiffBetweenNowAndTomorrow, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build()

WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(randomWorkRequest)
```

But I checked and the work wasn't executed when I woke up the next day.
Why isn't it being scheduled? Is there something wrong the way I calculate the timestamp of the next day?

Comment: Is the `OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<T>` your custom class? Do you want to eliminate standard builder because of passing class type in parameter?

Comment: It's just kotlin shortcut that comes with the work manager dependencies. You can add -ktx at the end to get kotlin friendly syntax with every architecture components.

Comment: Nice job ! ....

Answer (score 2):

As we see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110745313) in Google's issue tracker:

> Unfortunately, some devices implement killing the app from the recents menu as a force stop. Stock Android does not do this. When an app is force stopped, it cannot execute jobs, receive alarms or broadcasts, etc. So unfortunately, it's infeasible for us to address it - the problem lies in the OS and there is no workaround.

As a result, you need a `Service` to maintain your app alive. Also when the `Service` is terminated (doesn't matter what's the reason), it should start again and initialize your worker to be sure about its execution and keep the worker tasks alive. Here is an implementation of this idea using a `STICKY` `IntentService`.

**WallpaperService.kt**

```
import android.app.IntentService
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder
import androidx.work.WorkManager
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class WallpaperService : IntentService("WallpaperService") {

    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        intent?.apply {
            when (intent.action) {
                ACTION_SETUP_WORKER -> {
                    setupWorker()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
        // Define service as sticky so that it stays in background
        return Service.START_STICKY
    }

    private fun setupWorker() {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val currentTime = calendar.timeInMillis

        // for removing from recent apps test
        // calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10)

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)

        val tomorrowTime = calendar.timeInMillis
        val timeDiffBetweenNowAndTomorrow = tomorrowTime - currentTime

        Log.i("WallpaperService", "************  Tomorrow date is ${calendar.timeInMillis}")
        Log.i("WallpaperService", "************  Difference between now and tomorrow $timeDiffBetweenNowAndTomorrow")

        val randomWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<RandomWallpaperWorker>()
            .setInitialDelay(timeDiffBetweenNowAndTomorrow, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build()
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(randomWorkRequest)
    }

    companion object {

        const val ACTION_SETUP_WORKER = "ACTION_SETUP_WORKER"

        fun setupWorker(context: Context) {
            val intent = Intent(context, WallpaperService::class.java)
            intent.action = ACTION_SETUP_WORKER
            context.startService(intent)
        }
    }

}
```

**RandomWallpaperWorker.kt**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import androidx.work.Worker
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters

class RandomWallpaperWorker(val context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {

        // Do what you want here...

        Log.e("RandomWallpaperWorker", "*****************  DONE!" )
        WallpaperService.setupWorker(context)
        return Result.SUCCESS
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        WallpaperService.setupWorker(applicationContext)
    }

}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.aminography.workerapplication">

    <application ... >

        ...

        <service android:name=".WallpaperService" android:enabled="true"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: When I did it my way, the work was scheduled as I could see in the logs. Also, I was saving the ID into shared preferences so that I could confirm that the work has been scheduled. How is it different when the work is scheduled from an IntentService? Because once it's scheduled no matter from where it will run as expected right? How does scheduling from an IntentService differ from a Fragment?

Comment: `WorkManager` works in application layer, not OS. I mean it's running in  your application process, so when the process is killed, the worker manager object and its scheduled workers would be totally removed from memory. If you schedule the task for 10 seconds later, not tomorrow 9AM, then clear recent apps, you'll see that your scheduled worker won't be run. The above service avoids killing application for a long time. After its termination, it starts again and reschedules your task and makes us sure the worker tasks are still resident in memory.

Comment: @SriramR: Did you test it?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes the worker works as expected. Sometimes it doesn't. I'm just trying to debug it.

Comment: It worked as expected the first time I tried it. After that, it didn't work and the worker wasn't executed. The first time, for testing purposes, I set the Initial delay to 10 mins from when I was trying. The next time I tried it for 9 AM next day. That didn't work.

Comment: Would you please tell me your phone brand and OS specs?